# How to synchronize with all rendering commands has been completed in one draw call?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

There are three kinds of stuff to be rendered(3D points, surfaces and widgets). Basically, my `draw` function is as follows:

```
void draw()
{
    glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // activate shader
    shader->use();

    shader->setMat4("projection", projection);

    view = camera.GetViewMatrix();
    shader->setMat4("view", view);

    //draw 3D points
    glBindVertexArray(VAO_Vert);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,VBO_Vert);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size()*sizeof(float), vertices.data(), GL_STREAM_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    shader->setMat4("model",glm::mat4(1.0f));
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS,0,vertices.size() / 6);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    //draw surfaces
    glBindVertexArray(VAO_Sur);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,VBO_Sur);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, surfaces.size()*18*sizeof(float), surfaces.data(), GL_STREAM_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    shader->setMat4("model",glm::mat4(1.0f));
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,surfaces.size()*3);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);


    //draw coordinate system widget
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(widgetVertices), widgetVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(widgetIndices),widgetIndices,GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    shader->setMat4("model",model);

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,144,GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    // glfw: swap buffers and poll IO events (keys pressed/released, mouse moved etc.)
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
}
```

objects `shader` and `camera` are instances of [`class Shader`](https://learnopengl.com/code_viewer_gh.php?code=includes/learnopengl/shader_s.h) and [`class Camera`](https://learnopengl.com/code_viewer_gh.php?code=src/1.getting_started/7.4.camera_class/camera_class.cpp), separately.   Then we can make draw calls:

```
while(1)
{
    updateVerticesData();
    updateSurfaceDate();
    ...
    draw();
    ...
}
```

However, rendered stuff is not as plentiful as I anticipated:
[image] 
When I halt one second after draw call:

```
while(1)
{
    updateVerticesData();
    updateSurfaceDate();
    ...
    draw();
    sleep(1000); //halt one second
    ...
}
```

more stuff was rendered(in my case , more surfaces):
[image]
  am sure the problem is that not all rendering commands have been completed or issued 
 in one draw call, because each update will add numerous data to buffer.
[This page](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Synchronization) recommends two synchronization commands:`glFlush` and `glFinish`, but still not work for me. Who can help?

Comment: `glfwSwapBuffers` already implicitly flushes. I don't think that's the issue. We can't re-create your issue with the limited snippet you posted. Consider shrinking your example to a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: "*However, rendered stuff is not as plentiful as I anticipated.*" What do you mean by "plentiful" in this context?

Comment: @NicolBolas Hi, sorry for my late reply, I have added more details and descriptions

Comment: @Finley: We need to see a [mcve] in order to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Random thought - what is the depth clear value set to? Is it possible you're not clearing it to the correct value and some piece of geometry that is very near that value is getting partially drawn but not fully due to precision issues?